# How to test windows 7 application on MAC OS?

Tags: silverlight, macos, datetime, sharepoint-2010

I am developing silverlight web part for sharepoint 2010 using client object model. I have windows 7 os. Now I want to test may application on mac os. My client has mac os on some computer and windows 7 on some computer. On windows 7 the application is working properly but it is not working properly on MAC OS. I have textblock in which I am displaying time. On windows 7 time is displayed properly but not on mac os. I have the similar problem as in the following link

[Silverlight displays time zone info on mac and not PC using String("G") as format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297177/silverlight-displays-time-zone-info-on-mac-and-not-pc-using-stringg-as-forma)

So I have done the modifications in my code as suggested in the above link. Now I want to test it on broeser of mac os. So I am searching for any free emulator. But I found no such emulator with browser support. I dont have setup file for mac os. Can you please provide me any code or link or solution through which I can find any emulator or any software supported in windows 7 on which I can test the application in browser of mac os ? Or should I test it in safari on windows 7 ? Will it give me the same result as on mac os?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a tutorial how to install a mac os virtualmachine so you got a mac in your windows PC.
[Tutorial- Installing Virtualmachine/](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-install-os-x-snow-leopard-in-vmware-windows-7-9140301/)

Comment: Thanks for reply but it requires original OS X Snow Leopard retail disk.

Comment: if you need a OS X Snow Leopard retail disk you cant jsut downlaode it for free :P otherwise you have to do it inappropriate and pirate it but I don't know any pages where you can downloade this sry ...